# My tensorflow queue get filled slower when I increase the number of threads pushing data to it

Tags: tensorflow, python-multiprocessing

I've written some code to push data to a queue in tensorflow, the init of my queue handler and the main function run by all the threads are the following:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.X = tf.placeholder(tf.int64)
    self.Y = tf.placeholder(tf.int64)
    self.queue = tf.RandomShuffleQueue(dtypes=[tf.int64, tf.int64],
                                       capacity=100,
                                       min_after_dequeue=20)

    self.enqueue_op = self.queue.enqueue([self.X, self.Y])


def thread_main(self, sess, coord):
    """Cycle through the dataset until the main process says stop."""
    train_fs = open(data_train, 'r')
    while not coord.should_stop():
        X_, Y_ = get_batch(train_fs)
        if not Y: #We're at the end of the file
            train_fs = open(data_train, 'r')
            X, Y = get_batch(train_fs)
        sess.run(self.enqueue_op, feed_dict={self.X:X_, self.Y:Y_})
```

I am monitoring the size of my queue during the training. For some reasons my queue is filled slower when I increase the number of threads pushing data to it. Any idea why? Is it because I'm reading from a python file concurrently?

***EDIT:***

Here is the code I am using, beside the data and the graph it is exactly the same. The code is behaving as expected on this dummy data. I have two observation:

- I don't think I am closing the threads appropriately, it seems they get stuck to the queue after execution and the more I run the code the slower it gets.
- Since the multithreading is doing its job here I guess the only two points of failure are my graph and the way I have to read the data.

First, to generate a dummy dataset:

```
data_train = "./test.txt"

with open(data_train, 'w') as out_stream:
    out_stream.write("""[1,2,3,4,5,6]|1\n[1,2,3,4]|2\n[1,2,3,4,5,6]|0\n[1,2,3,4,5,6]|1\n[1,2,5,6]|1\n[1,2,5,6]|0""")

def get_batch(fs):
    line = fs.readline()
    X, Y = line.split('|')
    X = eval(X)
    Y = eval(Y)
    return X, Y
```

Then the queue controller:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import threading

tf.reset_default_graph()#Reset the graph essential to use with jupyter else variable conflicts

class QueueCtrl(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.X = tf.placeholder(tf.int64)
        self.Y = tf.placeholder(tf.int64)
        self.queue = tf.RandomShuffleQueue(dtypes=[tf.int64, tf.int64],
                                           capacity=100,
                                           min_after_dequeue=20)

        self.enqueue_op = self.queue.enqueue([self.X, self.Y])


    def thread_main(self, sess, coord):
        """Cycle through the dataset until the main process says stop."""
        train_fs = open(data_train, 'r')
        while not coord.should_stop():
            X_, Y_ = get_batch(train_fs)
            if not Y_: #We're at the end of the file
                train_fs = open(data_train, 'r')
                X_, Y_ = get_batch(train_fs)
            sess.run(self.enqueue_op, feed_dict={self.X:X_, self.Y:Y_}) 

    def get_batch_from_queue(self):
        """
        Return one batch
        """
        return self.queue.dequeue()

    def start_threads(self, sess, coord, num_threads=2):
        """Start the threads"""
        threads = []
        for _ in range(num_threads):
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.thread_main, args=(sess, coord))
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()
            threads.append(t)
        return threads
```

Then we build a dummy graph:

```
queue_ctrl = QueueCtrl()
X_, Y_ = queue_ctrl.get_batch_from_queue()
output = Y_ * tf.reduce_sum(X_)
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
```

Finally we iterate over the data:

```
sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(init)
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
my_thread = queue_ctrl.start_threads(sess, coord, num_threads=6)

for i in range(100):
    out = sess.run(output)
    print("Iter: %d, output: %d, Element in queue: %d" 
              % (i, out, sess.run(queue_ctrl.queue.size())))

coord.request_stop()
for _ in range(len(my_thread)): #if the queue is full at that time then the threads won't see the coord.should_stop
    _ = sess.run([output])

coord.join(my_thread, stop_grace_period_secs=10)
sess.close()
```

Here is the 25 first outputs with five threads:

```
Iter: 0, output: 21, Element in queue: 27
Iter: 1, output: 21, Element in queue: 37
Iter: 2, output: 20, Element in queue: 51
Iter: 3, output: 21, Element in queue: 67
Iter: 4, output: 20, Element in queue: 81
Iter: 5, output: 20, Element in queue: 89
Iter: 6, output: 21, Element in queue: 100
Iter: 7, output: 20, Element in queue: 100
Iter: 8, output: 20, Element in queue: 100
Iter: 9, output: 21, Element in queue: 100
Iter: 10, output: 20, Element in queue: 100
Iter: 11, output: 20, Element in queue: 100
Iter: 12, output: 21, Element in queue: 100
Iter: 13, output: 21, Element in queue: 100
Iter: 14, output: 20, Element in queue: 100
Iter: 15, output: 20, Element in queue: 100
Iter: 16, output: 21, Element in queue: 100
Iter: 17, output: 21, Element in queue: 100
Iter: 18, output: 20, Element in queue: 100
Iter: 19, output: 21, Element in queue: 100
Iter: 20, output: 21, Element in queue: 100
Iter: 21, output: 21, Element in queue: 100
Iter: 22, output: 20, Element in queue: 100
Iter: 23, output: 21, Element in queue: 100
Iter: 24, output: 21, Element in queue: 100
Iter: 25, output: 21, Element in queue: 100
```

With one thread:

```
Iter: 0, output: 21, Element in queue: 22
Iter: 1, output: 20, Element in queue: 25
Iter: 2, output: 20, Element in queue: 27
Iter: 3, output: 20, Element in queue: 29
Iter: 4, output: 21, Element in queue: 31
Iter: 5, output: 20, Element in queue: 32
Iter: 6, output: 20, Element in queue: 34
Iter: 7, output: 21, Element in queue: 35
Iter: 8, output: 21, Element in queue: 36
Iter: 9, output: 21, Element in queue: 38
Iter: 10, output: 20, Element in queue: 40
Iter: 11, output: 20, Element in queue: 42
Iter: 12, output: 20, Element in queue: 43
Iter: 13, output: 21, Element in queue: 46
Iter: 14, output: 20, Element in queue: 47
Iter: 15, output: 21, Element in queue: 48
Iter: 16, output: 20, Element in queue: 53
Iter: 17, output: 20, Element in queue: 56
Iter: 18, output: 21, Element in queue: 57
Iter: 19, output: 21, Element in queue: 61
Iter: 20, output: 21, Element in queue: 63
Iter: 21, output: 20, Element in queue: 67
Iter: 22, output: 21, Element in queue: 70
Iter: 23, output: 21, Element in queue: 73
Iter: 24, output: 20, Element in queue: 76
Iter: 25, output: 20, Element in queue: 78
```

Comment: most likely because the threads are contending the access to the queue. Can you post a small reproducible example?

Comment: I left the office, I'll face the code again tomorrow and will update the question. Also I will try to use a FIFO queue instead of a RandomShuffleQueue, and make sure the preprocessing is done by the CPU.

Comment: I've added some more code, I am still investigating.

Comment: Ok, after modifying the python code used to read the file I could see the queue being filled faster when adding more thread. Instead of reading byte after byte I now read line by line using `readline()`. I don't see why it changes anything, but it does... Also the queue gets filled faster with multiple threads, but the training is twice as long ... Probably the threads are constantly putting a mutex on the queue to do an enqueue, and the training op is fighting for the mutex as well. I could try to use `enqueue_many` but I have elements of multiple shapes so I cannot ...

Comment: Queues seem like an appealing feature of tensorflow, but so far I've spent 10 hours+ on it and got no speed gains. If you have sparse data and cannot afford to transform all your inputs in dense representation, then queues might not be the best option for you.

Comment: How many cores does your machine have?

Comment: 6 cores, 12 threads.

Answer (score 5):

Just want to add something here, I implemented a **multiprocess-based** data feeding pipeline for multi-task learning. It can achieve avg. GPU utilization >90% and quad-core CPU utilization >95%. Less prone to memory leak and particularly good for days-long training. Not saying it's perfect, but at least works much better than current TF queue API (1.1) in my case.

If anyone interested: https://hanxiao.github.io/2017/07/07/Get-10x-Speedup-in-Tensorflow-Multi-Task-Learning-using-Python-Multiprocessing/